# Write chunk of bytes one by one using writeCharacteristics using RxAndroidBLE

Tags: android, rx-java2, rxandroidble, rxbluetooth

I am trying to write the file to the controller using [RxAndroidBLE](https://github.com/dariuszseweryn/RxAndroidBle) library. Currently, i am reading a file and converting int `byte[]` and sending it to in chuck of `244`.

To perform this task i am using below flow

```
.flatMap(bytes -> getFileData())
.flatMapIterable(otaData -> otaData.getOtaByteArray())
.flatMapSingle(bytes -> mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_DATA, bytes))
.subscribe(bytes -> {

    Log.e(TAG,"Response Write "+Arrays.toString(BLEUtils.toHex(bytes)));

});
```

here `getFileData` is returning the `otaData` object.

the problem with this approach is all the byte array from `flatMapIterable` are getting flooded to `mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic` which is getting queued and then sent across to the controller. In this case controller is not able to read the data properly.

Hence i am looking for a way where once the `mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic`  function finishes writing one chuck of `244` it should then only pick the next `byte[]` array. I am not sure how to calibrate the streams here to be sure upon writing one chuck of block and then pick the next one using `RxAndroidBLE` and `RxJava`

Comment: "Hence i am looking for a way where once the mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic function finishes writing one chuck of 244 it should then only pick the next byte[] array." This is the default way Android works – it indicates that your receiver is not ready to receive the data and you need to synchronise somehow from the controller's application layer. Perhaps it is notifying when it is ready for more data?

Comment: Well in typical BLE Api (without using RxJava) when callback `onCharacteristicWrite` gets called for one chunk of data after that next list of btye array is taken hence i am search for such option. Moreover, when every item in the list completes i have to send the `03` to controller as well but on above code it is sending 03 everytime the `writeCharacteristics` gets executed

Comment: Android OS does not allow for writing next data packet before “onCharacteristicWrite” is called so you are executing the flow you describe. I cannot see any notion of “03” packet in your described code so I cannot relate. You need to elaborate and/or ask different questions.